# Reason for certain restrictions on variance conversions in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, implicit-conversion, contravariance, generic-variance

I have a few questions about the way implicit conversions between method delegates with regards to covariance and contravariance are implemented in C#.

```
delegate void ImplicitFunction<T>(T thing);
delegate void ExplicitFunction<in T>(T thing);
delegate void AnimalFunction(Animal thing);
delegate void DogFunction(Dog thing);

static void Process<T>(T thing) {
    // ...
}
static void AnimalProcess(Animal thing) {
    // ...
}

static void Main() {
```

From my understanding, variance handling
is implicit with regards to assigning a
function to a non-identical delegate, i.e.:

```
    ImplicitFunction<Dog> processObject = Process<Animal>;
```

(Conceptually, although possibly not semantically, I believe this is contravariance. Of course, if any of my assumptions are completely wrong, I would appreciate a correction.) After many hours of careful studying, I
believe I completely understand how this
works and why. But I have also learned
that I cannot convert a method from one
type (delegate) to another, even though
it is assigning the same value to the
same type, just in two steps:

```
    ImplicitFunction<Animal> tempProcessor = Process<Animal>;
    ImplicitFunction<Dog> processDogConv = tempProcessor; // compile error
```

Question 1: why not? And please do not say,
"because you do not use 'in'" or "because it
is not a generic type". I would like to know
what the justification is for this behavior,
in the same way that variance restrictions are
in place to prevent passing invalid types in
certain cases.
Now, I have also learned that C# supports
explicit delegate conversion using the keywords
'in' and 'out'. Like so:

```
    ExplicitFunction<Animal> processAnimal = Process<Animal>;
    ExplicitFunction<Dog> processDog = processAnimal;
```

But I can't do the same thing without generics:

```
    AnimalFunction processAnimalNonGeneric = AnimalProcess;
    DogFunction processDogNonGeneric = processAnimalNonGeneric; // compile error
```

I have a feeling the reason for this may be
closely related to the reason that implicit
variance conversions are not supported.

Question 2: But why? Why can't I use the 'in'
keyword something like so:

```
delegate void AnimalFunction(in Animal thing);
delegate void DogFunction(in Dog thing);
```

Once again, I know that just isn't how it
works, but what is the theoretical,
"we-can't-because-what-if-someone-did-this"
reason for excluding this functionality?

```
}
```

P.S. This code has been compiled to make sure it behaves as I describe, and all that is needed is a wrapper class and two empty `Dog : Animal` classes.

Comment: I think Eric Lippert should answer that http://blog.coverity.com/2014/06/18/delegates-structural-identity/#.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz It never occurred to me to reply to you, regrettably, but I'm not sure how the linked article answers either part of my question. Could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: "But I have also learned that I cannot convert a method from one type (delegate) to another, even though it is assigning the same value to the same type, just in two steps: [...] Question 1: why not?" - Eric answers that pretty well.

Comment: About the second question, I believe it is because it is unnecessary (it is easy to spot if there is covariance , contravariance or invariance, in the declaration itself - so using `in` or `out` is redundant). There might be more reasons which I unaware of... 

I think I'm gonna post your question in Eric's post - so he might enlighten us.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz Okay, I now see how Question 1 is answered, thanks. But the second part of my question was not why I couldn't specify `in` and `out` in the declaration, but rather why there isn't an explicit way to allow conversions between non-generic delegates. The declaration `in`/`out` was just an example as to how they might have provided this functionality.

Comment: Oh... Well, I predict that the answer would be that that feature was not " thought of, designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped to customers", and that that would cost money time and other resources, which could be used for more important features (there is a really simple work around here, so it's not that must-have feature).